# How to pass data from child component to root component

Tags: angular

I have a flag whose value changes if we do some operations. If the flag changes, I need to pass the changed value from the child component to root component.

As app component is a bootstrapped component, is there any way to pass on data from child to root so that I can get the data without loading the page?

I have tried @ViewChild as well as shared data service.

Comment: Have you try @Output Property

Comment: What's the issue with using a shared data service?

Comment: I have used @Output property to emit the changed flag till app.component. I am able to receive it in the immediate parent component, but its not getting triggered in app.component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subject observable in angular, You can push the your flag values to subject when any actions performs at child component level. You can subscribe that subjects in Root component. When ever any changes made to the subject in child component, Root component get the subject  values and you cna use output event emitters also in angular

Answer (score 0):

To pass data from child to a parent component you can :

1. Use `ViewChild() childComponent: ChildComponent;` and on the parent component use `childComponent.flag`
2. Create an `output()` and emit the flag with an EventEmitter
3. Create a `subject()` and `subscribe()` to it

Answer (score 0):

Use EventEmitter in child component and subscribe in parent component

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned you can use the @Output property that emits an event from the component to his parent or you can also use a shared service.

## @Output approach

#### class

```
export class FooComponent {
  @Output() fooEvent = new EventEmitter<fooType>();
}
```

#### template

you can trigger direct in the template

```
<button (click)="fooEvent.emit('fooType')">...
```

or call an method in the class if you need to do something before emit the event:

```
<button (click)="doSomethingBefore()">...
```

in the class the method calls the event

```
doSomethingBefore() {
  this.fooEvent.emit(fooType);
}
```

## Shared Service approach

Create a service and in the service create a property to store the data value, a subject to emits the latest value from your data and a method to get this subject.

#### shared service

```
export FooBarService {
  private data;
  private dataChanges$ = new BehaviorSubject<fooType>(this.data);

  get getData(): Observable<fooType> {
    return this.dataChanges$;
  }

  upadteData(data: fooType) {
    this.data = data;
    this.dataChanges$.next(this.data);
  }
}
```

in your components inject the service

#### Component that receives the data

```
export BarComponent implements OnInit {
  fooData$: Observable<fooType>;

  constructor(private fooBarService: FooBarService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fooData$ = this.fooBarService.getData;
  }
}
```

Stream the data in the template, so you don't need to care about subscribe and unsubscribe

```
<ng-container *ngIf="fooData$ | async"></ng-container>
```

#### Component that updates the data

now you just need to update the data in any component and the BarComponent will reveice this data

```
// FooComponent
export class FooComponent {
  constructor(private fooBarService: FooBarService) {}

  updateData() {
    this.fooBarService.updateData(// put your data);
  }
}
```

## what is the best?

It depends. I recommend the @Output approach if you don't need so much interaction with your data, otherwise a shared service is better because its cache your data.

> OBS: if you are working with a lot of input/output data maybe it is time to think about some application state management.

Answer (score -1):

Use EventEmitter in child component.

https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter

Child component:

```
@Output() flagChanged: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

change() {
  this.flagChanged.emit();
}
```

Parent component template:

```
<child (flagChanged)="onFlagChange($event)"></child>
```

Parent component:

```
onFlagChange() {
   console.log('Child flag has changed!')
}
```